# jquery: Replacing text is not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I need to replace the values between curly brackets with hyperlinks and assign those values to hyperlink

```
var description = "Hello world

This is the first test {f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link}

and some words 

This is the second test {587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}";
```

I have Array called HyperValues which is

```
var HyperValues = ["f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link"
                   ,"587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link"];

    $.each(HyperValues, function (key, value) {

                    var hyperLinkId = value.split(",")[0];
                    var hyperLinkText = value.split(",")[1];

  description.replace(/\{.+?\}/g, '<a id= ' + hyperLinkId + ' ' + 'class="infoBoxPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreInfoModal" href="#"> ' + hyperLinkText + '</a>');

            });
```

The above code works well but the problem is the string replaced with the latest
 item in the array i know i need another way for replacing the string

This is the output of the above code

[image: output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Im not expert at RegEx but I can pinpoint the logical error. $.each is looping over the array in correct fashion, however your /{.+?}/g will replace all the matching instance in string with the latest value. Ideally you will need to get the corresponding matching occurrence as you loop over the array, something like /{.+?}/g[key]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var description = `Hello world

This is the first test {f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link}

and some words 

This is the second test {587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}`;
var HyperValues = ["f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link"
                   ,"587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link"];

$.each(HyperValues, function (key, value) {

  var hyperLinkId = value.split(",")[0];
  var hyperLinkText = value.split(",")[1];
  //generate regular expression dynamically 
  //and test string ends with hyperLinkText + '}'
  var Reg = new RegExp('\\{.+?\\' + $.trim(hyperLinkText) + '}','g');
  
  description = description.replace(Reg, '<a id= ' + hyperLinkId + ' ' + 'class="infoBoxPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreInfoModal" href="#"> ' + hyperLinkText + '</a>');
});
            
$('body').html(description)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Is this result what you want?

---

```js
var description1 = `Hello world

This is the first test {f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link}

and some words 

This is the second test {587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}`;

var HyperValues = ["f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link"
                   ,"587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link"];
$.each(HyperValues, function (key, value) {

  var hyperLinkId = value.split(",")[0];
  var hyperLinkText = value.split(",")[1];
  // generate regular expression dynamically 
  // and test string ends with hyperLinkText + '}'
  // this regular is the something like /\{.+?First Link\}/g or /\{.+?Second Link\}/g
  // so for HyperValues[0] it will match '{f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link}' only
  // for HyperValues[1] it will match '{587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}' only
  var Reg = new RegExp('\\{.+?\\' + $.trim(hyperLinkText) + '}','g');
  
  description1 = description1.replace(Reg, '<a id= ' + hyperLinkId + ' ' + 'class="infoBoxPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreInfoModal" href="#"> ' + hyperLinkText + '</a>');
});



var description2 = `Hello world

This is the first test {f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link}

and some words 

This is the second test {587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}`;

var HyperValues2 = ["f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975"
                   ,"587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c"];// remove Fist Link and Second Link
                   
$.each(HyperValues2, function (key, value) {

  var hyperLinkId = value.split(",")[0];
  var hyperLinkText = value.split(",")[1];//because remove Fist Link and Second Link this will be undefined
  // because hyperLinkText is undefined now, then $.trim(hyperLinkText) = "" is just a empty string
  // so the reg below just work like the same as you wrote before /\{.+?\}/g
  // and it can't work of course
  // var Reg = new RegExp('\\{.+?\\' + $.trim(hyperLinkText) + '}','g');
  
  // now we can try to match the text by hyperLinkId
  // when it's HyperValues2[0] this reg work like /\{f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975.+?\}/g 
  // and will match {f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link}
  // when it's HyperValues2[1] this reg work like /\{587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c.+?\}/g 
  // and will match {587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}
  var Reg = new RegExp('\\{' + $.trim(hyperLinkId) + '.+?\\}','g');
  description2 = description2.replace(Reg, '<a id= ' + hyperLinkId + ' ' + 'class="infoBoxPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreInfoModal" href="#"> ' + hyperLinkText + '</a>');
});
            
$('#1').html(description1)
$('#2').html(description2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)  Your code is working very well, but i have a very small question 
what if  var HyperValues = [
  "f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975",
  "587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c"
];

I tried the follow reg but it didn't work

 var Reg = new RegExp('\\{.+?\\' + $.trim(hyperLinkText) + '}','g');

Can you please tell me the correct Reg format for this case

Comment: @Alex I edit my answer.And i recommend [regexper](https://regexper.com/) for you , where you can test your Regular Expression visually.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern will match two items so you need the first item in the HyperValues array to replace the first match in the string. Your code above was not swapping each regex match with the new text.

Also, since match() returns an array you can just use forEach() to loop it, no need for jQuery.

```
var desc = 'Hello world This is the first test {f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link} and some words This is the second test {587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link}';

var HyperValues = [
  "f19e7a87-3ae9-40d7-b81a-ad5eba8a2975, First Link",
  "587d2209-fcf2-448d-b52d-7f0c93e59c8c, Second Link"
];

desc.match(/\{.*?\}/g).forEach(function(match, i) {
  var singleHyperValue = HyperValues[i].split(",");
  desc = desc.replace(
    match,
    '<a id="' + singleHyperValue[0] + '" class="infoBoxPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreInfoModal" href="#">' + singleHyperValue[1] + '</a>'
  );
})
```

Working fiddle: https://jsbin.com/coxavusoge/edit?html,js,output